# Parsing a xml file from a specific web address using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml

I am a beginner to concepts of ElementTree in python. I created a simple program to extract some information from a xml file which was saved on my local computer.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='cricket.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
   print("%s - %s"%(child.get('srs'),child.get('mchDesc')))
```

Now, I want to use a xml file from a certain web address and extract information from that file. How can I do that without saving that file on local computer?

[Link of xml file](http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml)

Comment: Simply point to the web address: `tree = ET.parse('http://www.URLtoXML.xml')`. Then `tree.iter()` or `tree.get()` off any node.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of ElementTree's `fromstring()` method and the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module's `requests.get()` to accomplish this.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

> fromstring() parses XML from a string directly into an Element, which
>   is the root element of the parsed tree.

Install the requests module:

```
pip install requests
```

Use the [`requests.get()`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) to get your xml file from the url as a string.  Pass that into the `fromstring()` function.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import requests
tree = ET.fromstring(requests.get('http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml').text)
for child in tree:
   print("%s - %s"%(child.get('srs'),child.get('mchDesc')))
```

Results:

```
None - None
India tour of Sri Lanka, 2015 - Cricbuzz Cup - SL vs IND
Australia tour of Ireland, 2015 - IRE vs AUS
New Zealand tour of South Africa, 2015 - RSA vs NZ
Royal London One-Day Cup, 2015 - SUR vs KENT
Royal London One-Day Cup, 2015 - ESS vs YORKS
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.

Comment: Happy to help.  If this solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer.